# Concatenate Columns in Linq to SQL Select

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

I want to concatenate two column values based on condition of one column.

I am trying like this

```
select
{
     Orders=r.ordercode.length==0?r.order1:r.ordercode.length==3?r.order1+r.order2+r.order3
}
```

Comment: i figured out solution

Comment: And what is it? You can answer that yourself so others would know too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select
{
     Orders = (
                (r.ordercode.length == 0 || r.ordercode.length == 3) ? 
                    String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", r.order1, r.order2, r.order3) : 
                    String.Empty
              )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Orders=r.ordercode.length==0?r.order1:r.ordercode.length==3?string.concat(r.order1,", ",r.order2,", ",r.order3):""

Comment: I want order1 if length==0
if length==3 i to concat orders 1 to 3
else just display nothing so used ""

Comment: Check my answer please.